# Force wget proxy to non environment proxy

Tags: linux, wget, perl

Is there a way to force `wget` to use a specific squid proxy when making connections? I normally use a squid proxy, but I need this specific request to go via a different one. I don't have to use `wget`; I just need a way to test squid's blocking rules by requesting various pages through it. This proxy is not my normal proxy on the network, and so I can't rely on `wget` taking the environment variable.

Also, this is as part of a script, so anything that avoids editing `wget` config files would be best. Can `curl` do this? I'm currently using the exit code of `wget` to determine if the connection was made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `http_proxy` environment variable just for a specific invocation of wget:

```
http_proxy=http://specific-squid-proxy-host:3129/ wget http://server/page
```